# How to autoplay audio in android device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js, pixi.js

I know autoplay of audio does not support in android device. But i have come across one website which autoplays the music in android device.
http://kelvinh.studio/

So can anyone tell me how he is doing it?

Comment: the website won't play audio either.

Comment: it does autoplay audio in my android device.

Comment: even it worked on Android, it won't work on iOS devices

Comment: Yes, but can you tell me how it is working on Android device? and how i can implement in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it uses pixi.js.

It has sound module: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-sound

Here you can see a example with autoplay:

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-sound/blob/master/examples/index.html

About IOS:

> Playing sound on iOS — in any browser — requires a physical user
>   interaction. This is a browser limitation, and internal A-Frame events
>   (like fusing cursors) do not count as interaction. Ways to deal with
>   this include using a Begin Experience button to start ambient music.

Found in: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/sound.html

Comment: @jlvaquero, hey, there, do you know the trick of how pixi-sound implement autoplay?

Comment: no. Im sorry. Maybe you can figure it by reading the source code in github.